# Unity Shader Graph combine textures with transparency

Tags: unity, textures, unity-shader-graph

I have two transparent textures. border.png and text png. They are both white images with transparency for the parts I dont want to affect. What I want to achieve in shadergraph is to:

1: Put both textures on top of each other.
  2: Be able to adjust each textures color, including the textures to be white or black.

What I get is point 1, but if I try to put the color as black the texture becomes invisible (probably has something to do with transparency and how it is processed with black and white ...)

This is the best I managed to achieve with shadergraph but I still cant get the text color to be black. I have pretty much guessed my way till here so would appreciate if anyone can tell me if this is even the correct path to continue on...

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're just using the wrong blend mode and ordering in your last Blend node. Just do the same thing you did you draw the border over the background, to draw the text over them both:

[image: Shader graph example]

Comment: Thank you so much! I have been pulling my hair for so long trying to solve this. And the answer was so simple.. It works perfectly ! Really cant thank you enough.